# GRASS plugin not working properly

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-calculator

So I've been trying to make a master cost raster (taking into account the slope and landcover data). However I can't make the r.mapcalculator work...
 I tried with r.mapcalc but the interface looks so different from the tutorial I'm using (http://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Evaluating_Landscape_Permeability_in_Quantum) and I ended up not being able to perform the analysis.[image]

I also can't use any of the functions from the "GRASS commands" tab (even though the tab GRASS GIS 7 works fine. I tried installing QGIS over again, taking a look at the directory GRASS is installed and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system you are on and your method/source for installation and the version of QGIS.

Comment: I use OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. The QGIS version is 2.18.
I've got everything from kyngchaos.com. Maybe I messed up with the python modules or something like this?

Comment: If it was a Python issue I'd expect an error about GDAL when starting QGIS.  Also - have you seen [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187105/instructions-for-qgis-mac-installation)

Comment: Well, the r.mapcalculator script may not be present in your GRASS GIS version. BTW: There is an open ticket to re-introduce the script again: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3431

Comment: Oh, I see. So what tool would you recommend for someone that wants to combine the cost of different rasters?